# Does Anyone have any Idea why this Function is not running in a loop? Only one Youtube video is getting rendered

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to render multiple Youtube videos on the page using some JS. The first div with the class youtubevid gets rendered and turned into an Iframe. The rest of the videos do not get rendered. It's like the loop stops after the first div. Does anyone know why this would happen
This is the JFIDDle Link(https://jsfiddle.net/zondhe8j/21/)

This is the HTML

```
<div id="K1QICrgxTjA" data-step="1" class="youtubeVid" videosrc="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K1QICrgxTjA" videoid="K1QICrgxTjA"></div>

<div id="K1QICrgxTjA" data-step="1" class="youtubeVid" videosrc="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K1QICrgxTjA" videoid="K1QICrgxTjA"></div>

<div id="K1QICrgxTjA" data-step="1" class="youtubeVid" videosrc="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K1QICrgxTjA" videoid="K1QICrgxTjA"></div>

<div id="K1QICrgxTjA" data-step="1" class="youtubeVid" videosrc="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K1QICrgxTjA" videoid="K1QICrgxTjA"></div>
```

This is the JS

```
var hasVideo = document.getElementsByClassName('youtubeVid').length > 0;


if (hasVideo){
    var players = [];

    document.querySelectorAll('.youtubeVid').forEach(youtubeSection => {
        var vidID = youtubeSection.getAttribute('videoID');
        var title = youtubeSection.getAttribute('title');
        var type = youtubeSection.getAttribute('type');
        var playerName = youtubeSection.getAttribute('id');


        if (youtubeSection.getAttribute('videoSrc').includes('start')){
            var startTime = youtubeSection.getAttribute('videoSrc').split("start=");
            var startTime = startTime[1].split('&',1);
            var Start = startTime[0]
            if (youtubeSection.getAttribute('videoSrc').includes('end')){
                var endTime = youtubeSection.getAttribute('videoSrc').split("end=");
                var End = endTime[1];
            }
        }
        var player = {
            "playerName": playerName,
            "videoId": vidID,
            "vidTitle": title,
            "type": type,
            "startSeconds": Start || null,
            "endSeconds": End || null,
            "started": 0
        }
        players.push(player)
    })

    var playedIds = [];
    var endedIds = [];

    if (players.length > 0) {
        document.head.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('script'), {
            src: 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'
        }))

        window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
            var hasVideos = document.getElementsByClassName('youtubeVid');
            for(var i = 0; i < hasVideos.length;i++) {
                var curplayer = createPlayer(players[i]);
            }
        };

        function createPlayer(playerInfo) {
            for(var i = 0; i < players.length ;i++) {
                return new YT.Player(playerInfo.playerName, {
                    videoId: playerInfo.videoId,
                    playerVars: {rel: 0, showinfo: 0, ecver: 2},
                    startSeconds: playerInfo.startSeconds,
                    endSeconds: playerInfo.endSeconds,
                    events: {
                        'onReady': function (e) {
                            e.target.cueVideoById({
                                videoId: playerInfo.videoId,
                                startSeconds: playerInfo.startSeconds,
                                endSeconds: playerInfo.endSeconds,
                            });
                            console.log('video ready');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For one thing, there can't be duplicates of 'id' in an HTML page. Those are just 1 per page, so - you could consider using a data-attr like `data-video-id=''` or something.

Comment: All of your videos have the same "playerName". I guess the `YT` script is smart enough not to create multiple players with the same ID. Make those unique.

Comment: I think it's just overwriting the player 3 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use differents ID on html

```
<div id="K1QICrgxTjA_1" data-step="1" class="youtubeVid" videosrc="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K1QICrgxTjA" videoid="K1QICrgxTjA"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah.

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/ja1k4s3w/

and - in general / when making a test like this --- use better example data - instead of 4 of the same video. Too many quirks could happen. Why would youtube want to load the same video 4 times... things might be mysterious.

Comment: Thank you Ill try out the suggestion. Using the same video because at different steps the video will play at different points. So i reference the same video multiple times